# Copy dependency to war before packaging

Tags: java, maven, packaging

I'm packaging an ear file with maven for an IBM Content Navigator plugin project. This product requires to have an ear, which includes a war, and that war should include the plugin as jar in the root of the war. So not in the WEB-INF/lib. The ear and the war are just empty containers.
So I've created 3 projects, an ear, a web project, and a simple java project. All of these projects have a pom.
How can I create a war which includes the simple java project (jar) in the root of the war? It is not just a dependency as it must not end up in the WEB-INF/lib.

Thanks in advance,
Roeland Bestman

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `maven-dependency-plugin`'s `copy` goal and place the jar in a directory under the `target` directory. Then you'll need to include it from there into your war using the `maven-assembly-plugin`.